# render threw an error in 'lightning:treeGrid' [can't convert undefined to object]

Tags: apex, lightning-aura-components

I am testing using lightning:treeGrid.
I am facing this error
render threw an error in 'lightning:treeGrid' [can't convert undefined to object]

### ## Lightning Component ##

```
<aura:attribute name="gridCol" type="List" />
<aura:attribute name="gridData" type="Object" />

<aura:handler name="init" value="{!this}" action="{!c.doInitTree}"/>

<lightning:treeGrid columns="{!v.gridCol}"
    data="{!v.gridData}"
    keyField="id"
    aura:id="mytree"
/>
```

---

### Js controller

---

```
doInitTree: function(component, event, helper) {
    var callApexCtrl = component.get('c.getlistTreeGrid');
    callApexCtrl.setCallback(
        this,
        function(response){
            var state = response.getState();
            if(component.isValid()&&state==="SUCCESS"){
                var tree =response.getReturnValue();
                var obj=[];
                //Change "Contacts" key to "_children"
            for(var i=0; i<tree.length;i++) {
                tree[i]._children = tree[i]['Jalons__r'];
                delete tree[i].Jalons__r; 

            }
              alert('Alert1 :'+JSON.stringify(tree));
                var columns = [
                    {
                        type: 'text',
                        fieldName: 'Label',
                        label: 'stage'
                    }
                ];
                component.set("v.gridCol", columns);
                component.set("v.gridData", tree);

            }

        }

    );
    $A.enqueueAction(callApexCtrl);
}
```

---

### Apex Controller

---

```
public class Milestone {
@AuraEnabled
public static list<Stage__mdt> getlistTreeGrid(){
   list<Stage__mdt> listvaleur=new list<Stage__mdt>([SELECT  Label,IsSelect__c,(SELECT Label, IsSelect__c  FROM Jalons__r) FROM Stage__mdt]);
    return listvaleur;
}
}
```

---

### My alert result

---

```
Alert1 :[{"Label":"Stage1","Id":"m02580000008kBjAAI","_children":[{"Stages__c":"m02580000008kBjAAI","Id":"m04580000000DRVAA2","Label":"Milestone1"},{"Stages__c":"m02580000008kBjAAI","Id":"m04580000000DRLAA2","Label":"Milestone1"}]},{"Label":"Stage3","Id":"m02580000008kBtAAI","_children":[{"Stages__c":"m02580000008kBtAAI","Id":"m04580000000DRkAAM","Label":"Milestone3"}]},{"Label":"Stage2","Id":"m02580000008kBoAAI","_children":[{"Stages__c":"m02580000008kBoAAI","Id":"m04580000000DRfAAM","Label":"Milestone2"},{"Stages__c":"m02580000008kBoAAI","Id":"m04580000000DRaAAM","Label":"Milestone1"}]}]
```

---

---

[image]

---

could someone explain me what is wrong ?

Comment: Where is the actual error being throw i.e in the js controller? By the error it sounds like the thing you are trying to convert is null

Comment: the error is throw on the ui /components/lightning/treeGrid.js

Comment: Yes but what line. It says 156 in your js controller. Can you hightlight the line in your code?

Comment: TreeGrid.js  is inside lightning's api. it is Lightning.treeGrid implementation. It is not in my implémentation

Comment: I am having the exact same issue... anybody has an idea why this is happening? Any solution?

Answer (score 0):

I just found a workaround. It worked well when I surrounded the lightning:treeGrid with a an aura:if.

```
<aura:attribute name="treeIsVisible" type="Boolean" default="false" access="PRIVATE" description="display the tree only when all its data is ready in the JS controller"/>
<aura:if isTrue="{! v.treeIsVisible}">
  <lightning:treeGrid columns="{! v.gridColumns }" data="{! v.gridData }" keyField="id" aura:id="mytree"/>
</aura:if>
```

I set the "treeIsVisible" attribute to false by default. In the JS controller (or the helper), right after setting the gridColumns and gridData, I set treeIsVisible to true. In other words, I only display the tree when I am certain that the its attributes has values.

It seems to me that this is a bug of the lightning:treeGrid component. It should work without having to use an aura:if.